# I am POST-ing an array of objects to my API. How can I access the properties of those objects?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following database table:

```
Table: Locations
Columns: id, lat, lng, user_id
```

I'm currently POST-ing a markers array the contains 2 JavaScript objects from the front-end to the back-end that have lat and lng properties. I'm trying to figure out how would I assign the lat and lng properties in my foreach loop. I just can't figure out how to access them.

My POST

```
    data: function() {
        return {
            markers: [{lat: 42, lng: 24}, {lat: 11, lng: 22}]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        saveLocations(){
            axios.post('/location', {
                userId: 1,
                markers: this.markers
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    }
```

PHP

```
public function newLocation(Request $request){
    $markers = $request['markers'];

    foreach ($markers as $marker) {
        $location = new Location();
        $location->user_id = 1;
        $location->lat = ;
        $location->lng = ;
        $location->save();
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully added locations!'
    ], 201);
}
```

Comment: You can get post and get input from the request using this syntax: `$request->input('markers');` also to keep in mind you should validate this input, there's good documentation of requests here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests

Comment: show us `dd($markers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your foreach loop use it like this

```
foreach ($markers as $marker) {
        $location = new Location();
        $location->user_id = 1;
        $location->lat = $marker['lat'];
        $location->lng = $marker['lng'];
        $location->save();
}
```